# Why master user does not have all privileges on all tables in RDS postgres?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, psql, rds

In RDS postgres, I have a user/role named `master_user` with `rds_superuser` permission.

1. I created a new db user `user1` using the master username/password.
2. I created a db table named `test_table` using the new user `user1`.
3. I created a new db user `user2` using the master username/password;
4. I tried to grant all privileges on all tables for `user2` while using master username/password. However, I got errors like this:

```
postgres=> GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO user2;
ERROR:  permission denied for relation test_table
```

Why I still got permission denied error while using the master username&password? What's the workaround here?

Comment: did you ever find the solution?

Comment: this is great question. i am surprised nobody answered..... i guess it is not as in mysql on sql server ....